# Word document error

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2

I am trying use a Word document from my application on a Windows 2008 server 64bit from my MVC 2 application. I encountered this error message:

> System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Retrieving the COM class factory
>   for component with CLSID {000209FF-0000-0000-C000-000000000046} failed
>   due to the following error: 80070005 Access is denied. (Exception from
>   HRESULT: 0x80070005 (E_ACCESSDENIED)).
>   at
>   System.RuntimeTypeHandle.CreateInstance(RuntimeType type, Boolean
>   publicOnly, Boolean noCheck, Boolean& canBeCached,
>   RuntimeMethodHandleInternal& ctor, Boolean& bNeedSecurityCheck)
>   at
>   System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceSlow(Boolean publicOnly, Boolean
>   skipCheckThis, Boolean fillCache)
>   at
>   System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceDefaultCtor(Boolean publicOnly,
>   Boolean skipVisibilityChecks, Boolean skipCheckThis, Boolean
>   fillCache)
>   at System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type type, Boolean
>   nonPublic).

I have tried all know solutions, but still cannot fix it.

Comment: How do I know the application pool user..?

Comment: http://www.iis.net/learn/manage/configuring-security/application-pool-identities

Answer (score 1):

> First of all, please note that serverside office interop isn't
>   officially supported by Microsoft:
>   http://support.microsoft.com/kb/257757

Nevertheless I got a similar scenario running with power point and had to do the following steps to get rid of the error you describe:

1. Run Microsoft Management Console (mmc.exe)
2. Add Snap-In for "Component Services"
3. Search for Computers\My Computer\DCOM Config\<strike>Microsoft Office Power Point Slide</strike>\ (you may search for something that sounds correct for your word-scenario)
4. Open Properties > Tab "Security"
5. "Launch and Activation Permissions" > Edit ...
6. Add your application pool user to this list and allow "Local Launch" and "Local Activation"